# Node js not Working on 3000 port although showing it is running

Tags: express

I have started my express server script via terminal and it is showing that the server has been started on port 3000, but nothing is working on port 3000.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(port)

console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`)
```

Comment: Can you share your code? It would be easier to help

Comment: What do you mean by ' nothing is working on 3000 port'?
You havent written any route so it wouldnt work

Comment: app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hey');
});
Add this piece at the end.
Also.
Refer this:-  http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: hi i have written routes and everything is working properly in my local but when i uploaded it no live started the services this problem has occured , actually it is show that it is working on 3000 port but nothing has been found when i visited on my IP